# How to check whether my input data is already in normalized form or not

Tags: machine-learning, normalize

I am writing a program for yolov3. in that program user will give co-ordinates of bounding boxes and class id as input. but user can give input in both normalized format or in de normalized format. after the user gives input I want to whether the input given is normalized (0 to 1) or not. if normalized then i am gonna de-normalize it. so my question how will I check the co-ordinates are normalized or not. what is that key feature which will differentiate between normalized input and de-normalized input.

Answer (score 0):

right now I could only think of checking whether my input lies between 0 and 1. if yes it is normalized.